# File-based reverse proxy cache with lru gc?

Tags: reverse-proxy, cache

For a project I'm working on I need a file-based reverse proxy cache where I limit the size of the cache to some setting and have the ability to "gc" the cache based most likely on a lru algorithm.

I'm not seeing anything like this with Apache, Nginx, Cherokee,... but I may have missed it.

Any pointers would be appreciated-- thanks.

Comment: FYI we're looking at Varnish for this.